# Python: Compound Try/Except Blocks

Tags: python

I am working on a random word picker (used in the command line). The word picker itself works perfectly (I have a text file that has a bunch of words separated by spaces. The program will take the text file and make a list, the entries being everything in the list split with spaces).

The next step I want to take is to be able to programmatically add words to the text file. I was able to get it to add whatever the user gives from input, but now I want to make sure that the word provided from the user doesn't have spaces, numbers, or uppercase letters.

The first attempt I took looked like this:

```
def add_word():
     word_to_add = input("Word to add: ")

     valid_word = False
     if any(char.isdigit() for char in word_to_add):
          valid_word = False
     elif any(char.isupper() for char in word_to_add):
          valid word = False
     elif any((" " in chars) for chars in word_to_add):
          valid word = False
     else:
          valid word = True
```

I know this is a *super* inefficient method to use. That said, I'm trying to use Try/Except blocks to clean it up a little bit. I think I have an idea of how they work. Since I'm trying to test against multiple conditions, it would be something like

```
try:
     # code for no numbers
try: 
     # code for no uppercases
try:
     # code for no spaces
except:
     # blah blah blah
else:
     # blah blah blah
```

Now, the dilemma I'm facing is how do I route each `try:` to a specific exception? What I mean is if there is an exception with the numbers, it would print something like "your word cannot contain numbers! Try again." and the same deal for spaces and uppercases. Is there a way for me to make something like this:

```
try:
     # if there's a number go to exception A
try:
     # if there's an uppercase go to exception B
try:
     # if there's a space go to exception C
exception a:
     # blah blah blah
exception b:
     # blah blah blah
exception c:
     # blah blah blah
else:
     # blah blah blah
```

Would it end up being more efficient to just have multiple try/except blocks or a "compound" version like the above code?

The reason I don't want to use if/elif/else is because sometimes it will still add the user input to the word list even if `valid_word` was false.

Sorry that I can't be more specific here, I just don't really know how to articulate what I'm trying to accomplish here. Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: "I know this is a super inefficient method to use" Why do you think this solution is inefficient?

Comment: "super inefficient" - no.  The switch is more efficient than the try-catch stuff. IMHO, it is generally stylistically best to use try-catch for *program* errors, not for *user* errors.  E.g., you end up with a digit in a string that you, the programmer, thought would always be non-digits - "How did that get there?".  This should raise an exception.  This is just a general stylistic thing (like the oxford comma) so take this with a grain of salt.  Still, the ifthen switch I think is much better here.

Comment: Just to be clear: exceptions are, in general, very expensive (with respect to other solutions to solve a given problem). What would be *more* efficient would simply be to make a single pass, and even a single assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `raise` an exception inside a `try` block to immediately jump to a matching `except`, e.g.:

```
def add_word():
    while True:
        word_to_add = input("Word to add: ")
        try:
            if any(char.isdigit() for char in word_to_add):
                raise ValueError("Your word cannot contain numbers!")
            if any(char.isupper() for char in word_to_add):
                raise ValueError("Your word cannot contain capitals!")
            if " " in word_to_add:
                raise ValueError("Your word cannot contain spaces!")
        except ValueError as err:
            print(err)
            print("Try again")
        else:
            break
    # now do whatever you need to do to add word_to_add
```

But you could just as easily structure this as an `if/elif` block where each error condition is an `elif` and you `break` the loop in the `else`:

```
def add_word():
    while True:
        word_to_add = input("Word to add: ")
        if any(char.isdigit() for char in word_to_add):
            print("Your word cannot contain numbers!")
        elif any(char.isupper() for char in word_to_add):
            print("Your word cannot contain capitals!")
        elif " " in word_to_add:
            print("Your word cannot contain spaces!")
        else:
            break
        print("Try again!")
    # now do whatever you need to do to add word_to_add
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can only have one `try`. But it can have multiple `except`s. You cannot stack multiple tries. You can legally `try`s inside each other just like you nest `if` statements or `for` loops. But there isn't much reason to do this in a single function since you can stack multiple `except`s on a single `try`.
2. The code in the `except` will only be called when some code `raise`s an error in the `try`. This most commonly happens when you call a function which then raises an error. But you can also manually `raise` in the `try`.